# Setting multiple arraylist to shared preferences

Tags: java, android

I am new to android , i have a three string Array list (File Path, Amount,Date) how should i save it to shared preferences in android studio?

```
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
                set2.addAll(Cheque_amount);
                edit.putStringSet("Key1", set1);
                edit.commit();

Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();
                set2.addAll(Cheque_amount);
                edit.putStringSet("Key2", set2);
                edit.commit();
```

using Hashset like this not working ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Gson for this.

Convert your array or object to Json with Gson library and store your data as String in json format.

Save to preferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(your_array_list);
editor.putString(TAG, json);
editor.commit();
```

To Read from preferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = sharedPrefs.getString(TAG, "");
Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
List<String> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: i do not want to create object , i want to send simple multiple string arraylist .    Can i do this..   Gson gson = new Gson();                                                                                               //file_paths,amount,date are arraylist
String json1 = gson.toJson(file_paths);                                                                       String json2 = gson.toJson(amount);                                                                       String json3 = gson.toJson(date);

Comment: yes you can do that, check the answer closely. In save to preferences I have shown you that only.